# Initialize Array of LongArray in Kotlin

Tags: data-structures, kotlin

I basically wanted to create 2D array whose size is known to me on **runtime**

I have declare and array of `LongArray` as below

```
private lateinit var optionalGroup: Array<LongArray>
```

And I can assign value to it as below where **group** is my `Mutable Map`

```
 group.forEach { (key, value) -> optionalGroup[key - 1] = LongArray(value) }
```

My question is how can I initialize optionalGroup with size as of group ? I tried

```
`optionalGroup = Array(group.size)
```

> thows error No value passed for parameter 'init'`

Comment: To create an array you need to pass the initial values of the array. `Array(group.size) { LongArray(0) }` should work, but you will also overwrite all the values later. Consider using a `MutableList` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an array, you have no choice but to initialize the initial values of each element

```
optionalGroup = Array(group.size) { LongArray(0) }
```

I suggest you use a mutable list instead to avoid having to initialize the elements:

```
private lateinit var optionalGroup: MutableList<LongArray>
optionalGroup = mutableListOf()
```

If this is not an option, you can still use a temporary mutable list and convert it back to a typed array:

```
val tempList = mutableListOf<LongArray>()
group.forEach { (key, value) -> tempList[key - 1] = LongArray(value) }
optionalGroup = tempList.toTypedArray()
```

Comment: Generally you should avoid arrays and use lists whenever possible ;)